# Require.js Backbone.js Router to ES6 - How to dynamically load imports based on the Route

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, ecmascript-6

I'm converting my Backbone.js Router which used require into the ES6 standard using import statements.

In my router function I would normally have something like:

```
"about" : function about()
           {
            require(['aboutObj'],        
                    function(aboutView)
                     {
                      new mysite.about.View();
                     });
           }
```

which would specify a route to my about page and would load in the about page object.  From what I read online I would need to add import statements to the top of my route to be ES6 compliant, but how can I load in only that object when the router hits the about page url?

Comment: use the run-time import: `System.import('some_module')` i'm not 100% sure how compat it is, but that's what it is/was supposed to do last i heard. Maybe it got moved to ES7?

Comment: hmm @dandavis, doesn't seem to be the out of the box solution.  I'm getting a system is undefined error.

Comment: you might need to "polyfill" `System`, that part alone is famous.